# HQL Query returning HibernateProxy objects

Tags: hibernate, jpa, proxy

I'm using Hibernate 6 in a JSF (Jakarta EE 10) project. I have the following method:

```
private void iniciarListas() {
    atualizarLotesAves();
    setAviarios(aviarioDAO.listarAtivos());
    setCooperados(usuarioDAO.listarPorPerfil(PerfilEnum.COOP));
    setLinhagensGeneticas(linhagemGeneticaDAO.listarAves());
    setIncubatorios(empresaDAO.listarTodos());
    setDiasSemanaEnum(DiaSemanaEnum.listar());
}
```

The method "usuarioDAO.listarPorPerfil(PerfilEnum.COOP)" is returning a list of "Usuario$HibernateProxy" objects, but if I reverse the order of the code and put "setCooperados" before "setAviarios", the list of users is returned correctly, but the method "aviarioDAO.listarAtivos()" starts returning a list of "Aviario$HibernateProxy".

To me, this doesn't make sense, just reversing the order of the lines solves the problem with one and causes a problem with another.

Proxy is caused in the "Aviarios" line:

```
setCooperados(usuarioDAO.listarPorPerfil(PerfilEnum.COOP));
setAviarios(aviarioDAO.listarAtivos());
```

Proxy is caused in the "Cooperados" line:

```
setAviarios(aviarioDAO.listarAtivos());
setCooperados(usuarioDAO.listarPorPerfil(PerfilEnum.COOP));
```

I'm not sure if it could be the way Hibernate loads entities.

Answer (score 0):

Proxies come into play when you have hibernate set for lazy loading.

If you want to convert the hibernate proxy objects to their real counterparts you can use the load method in the hibernate session. Or you can reconfigure for eager loading.